# Exit out of frame and create new frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
        switch(arg0.getKeyCode()) {
    //if keycode is 'd' key
    case 68:
        
        break;
        
    case 65:
        System.out.println("stuff for left key using a");
        break;

    case 87:
        shark.MoveUp();
        break;
    case 38:
        shark.MoveUp();
        break;
    case 82:
        new Game();
        break;
    }
```

So **Game** is the name of the class. This is not the JFrame. When I try calling the jframe, it does not recognize it. When I press "R", it creates a new game but it does not get rid of the old game. When the old game runs in the background, the new game becomes unplayable due to lag. How do I delete the old Game that is running and just run the new one I started in *case 82*?

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. We don't know what those number in the switch statement mean. Instead use variable provided by the API such as `KeyEvent.VK_D`. Even better is to not use a switch statement and instead use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which is how all Swing components work. Don't attempt to create a new frame. If you want to restart your game then you should have a `reset()` method. to stop playing the old game and reset the values/variables for the new game. The is how games like MineSweeper work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd highly recommend on using JFrame.dispose() ONthe old Game as long as it expanding JFrame. If not you can add a method to the Game class that will dispose the JFrame it contains. A method as such will look like that:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("game");//Lets assume thats your frame in Game

//that should be your method inside of Game class:
public void gameDispose(){
if(frame != null)
    frame.dispose();
}
```

Now the only problem you may be in is not being able to call this dispose method since your Game is not inside of a variable. Therefore when Game is created it should happen inside of a variable as follow:

```
Game g = new Game();//Just for understaning of g variable.
```

Later when needed call your method.

Therefor your code should look like this:

```
Game g = new Game();
    switch(arg0.getKeyCode()) {
    //if keycode is 'd' key
    case 68:
        
        break;
        
    case 65:
        System.out.println("stuff for left key using a");
        break;

    case 87:
        shark.MoveUp();
        break;
    case 38:
        shark.MoveUp();
        break;
    case 82:
        g.dispose().
        g = new Game()
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I made JFrame f = new JFrame("The Shark Game"); inside of public Game() so I cant use the JFrame name outside the game method. What do I do... here is the code `public void gameDispose(){
  
  if( f!= null)
      f.dispose();
  }`   It gives me an error at "f" part cause JFrame f is in the game method and for some reason I cant use it outside of that method.

Comment: the rson for that is that f is most likely not a public variable of Game class. all you need to do is make it as such just as i did in my example.